# The Arts and Crafts of Problem Solving Problem 2.2.20

Tags: number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer.

We can find integers $a,b$ such that $1 \leq a < b \leq n$, $a+b > n$ and $a,b$ are relatively prime.

Then we find $\frac{1}{ab}$.

Then we sum all of the found fractions.

For example if $n=6$, the ordered pairs are 
$
(1,6),(5,6),(2,5),(3,5),(4,5),(3,4)
$
and the corresponding sum is 
$
\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{30} + \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{15} + \frac{1}{20} + \frac{1}{12} = \frac{1}{2}
$
Investigate what happens with the other values of $n$, and conjecture something.

What I have found so far is that the sum always stays the same but I am having issues proving that it is true.

$\textbf{Partial Solution}$

If we start experimenting with more values of $n$, such as $n = 2$. Then the ordered pairs are

(1,2)

Then the corresponding sum is

$
\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}
$

$n = 5$. Then the ordered pairs are

(1,5),(2,5),(3,5),(4,5),(3,4)

Then the corresponding sum is

$
\frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{10} + \frac{1}{15} + \frac{1}{20} + \frac{1}{12} = \frac{1}{2}
$

From this we can assume that the sum stays the same for all $n$
 in the positive integers

Comment: Induction indeed does works. I'm guessing that you're unwilling to write it out and so gave the -1. I've written up the complete answer and deleted it. If you show your work, I'd reveal my answer.

Comment: i've tried but i can't come with anything that's why I asked the question here. My only working that I could do is putting in different values of n and seeing what happens.

Comment: Do you know what induction is? If yes, what does the start of the proof look like? Edit that into the question (or write it up as a partial answer).

Comment: I know what induction is but the problem is I don't know where to start the proof. If you could help me with that I could possibly continue the proof.

Comment: What does the start of the proof look like? Edit that into the question (or write it up as a partial answer).

Comment: What does the start of the **proof by induction** look like?

Answer (score 1):

(My deleted solution shows more details.)

**Hint:** Induction.

Consider going from $n $ to $ n+1 $. (Use $n = 6$ to help think it through).

Step 1. Completely categorize all the pairs that you lose.

Step 2. Completely categorize all the pairs that you gain.

Step 3. Show that the sum from terms that you lose is equal to the sum from terms that you gain.

Step 4: Hence, the sum is a constant.